# How to create button for mobile to scan Barcode using html5 jquery or javasctipt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to trigger mobile phone camera to scan Barcode from html using jquery or javascript ?
I would like to create form and then button (when you clicked on mobile it will let you scan code and it will place the code on input field)
Is that possible?

Comment: checkout this library https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode

Comment: Thanks for response. This won't scan barcodes :(

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at: https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/

I haven't used it in any production code yet but have experimented with it.  Scanning good quality barcodes works well.  Scanning through plastic bags and shrink wrap is a bit iffy.  (To be fair, dedicated scanners also have issues there, but tend to do better.)

Tested only on Android with Chrome and Firefox.  Requires the most recent iOS/Safari to work on that platform.